# Add variable to data

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Im trying to concatenate a data with variable (Terraform v0.12.0):

```
variable "my_var" {
    default = "secret_string"
}

auth_token = data.external.get_secret.result.var.my_var
```

It's work in case of:

`auth_token = data.external.get_secret.result.secret_string`

As I can see I can't to add variable to data. Do we have any workaround for this case? Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here. Are you trying to concatenate the string returned by the external data source with the string in the `my_var` variable? Or are you trying to access an attribute of the external data sources return value with a key that matches the value or `my_var`?

Comment: I need to retrieve a key from secret..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very clear for what you need. Let me guess.

you can have different endpoints to save your secrets, such as hashicorp vault, aws ssm, aws secret managers, with these ways, you can avoid to save secrets directly in source code.

Here I use [aws ssm for an example](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ssm_parameter.html) on how to reference a secret via variable.

Suppose you have set SSM key `my_var` in aws.

```
variable "my_var" {
    default = "my_var"
}


data "aws_ssm_parameter" "read" {
  name  = "${var.my_var}"
}
```

So now you can easily reference it

```
auth_token             = "${aws_ssm_parameter.read.value}"
```

> Note: The unencrypted value of a SecureString will be stored in the raw state as plain-text.
>
> Note: The data source is currently following the behavior of the SSM API to return a string value, regardless of parameter type. For type StringList, we can use the built-in split() function to get values in a list. Example: split(",", data.aws_ssm_parameter.subnets.value)